# http status difference between console and result

Tags: angularjs, http, angular-ui

there is probably somehting that i don't understand about the staus in angularjs,
this is my code:

```
if((!isNaN($scope.toSearch))&&($scope.toSearch.length==11)){
        /*inizio case*/
        $http.get(server[0]+getServizi.piva[0].start.replace("variabile1",$scope.toSearch)+getServizi.piva[0].end.replace("variabile2",sigla))
            .success(function(data){
                /*completamento barra*/
                $scope.value=100;
                $scope.type='success';
                $scope.typeMessage=barmessage.success;
                /*getrisultato*/
                var resGet=data.RECORD[0].RICORRENZA[0].VIO001;
                var id=0;
                for(var i=0;i<data.RECORD[0].RICORRENZA[0].VIO001.length;i++){
                    if((resGet[i].STAATT=='R')&&(resGet[i].CCIAA==resGet[i].PRVSEDE)){
                        id=id+1;
                        $scope.risultato.push({id:id,
                                    ragioneSociale:resGet[i].RAGSOC,
                                    indirizzo:resGet[i].VIO011[0].S2VIA1+" "+resGet[i].VIO011[0].VIASEDE+" "+resGet[i].VIO011[0].NCIVSEDE+" "+resGet[i].VIO011[0].FRAZSEDE+" "+resGet[i].VIO011[0].S2COMUNI1,
                                    codiceFiscale:resGet[i].CODFIS,
                                    tipoSocieta:resGet[i].S2NATGIU,
                                    attivita:resGet[i]['CISTAT07-XD']
                                    });
                        };
                    }
                })
            .error(function(data,status){
                /*completamento barra*/
                $scope.value=100;
                $scope.type='danger';
                $scope.typeMessage=barmessage.danger;
                $scope.alerts.push({ type: 'danger', msg: 'Errore numero: ' });
                /*getrisultato*/
                alert("errore richiesta ricerca "+status);
            });
```

so the problem is that when i send a wrong url i always receive a 404 status message in the alert, but in the console log the things are different for example a 500 status, other than that any one knows how can i do to catch the error message to?

Comment: you should simplify your code first!

Comment: it isn't possible, for now, even if you can believe it it's a lot simplify between the starter one:)

Comment: 1. Can you provide plunkr or jsfiddle example?
2. Where is console.log? How do you get the result in console? Try logging the status in error handler.

Comment: i'm waiting for the eight hours to write the answer but i have already solve this problem thank you anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem were solve by himself, since i have deploy thee application on the server i always get the right status code message